# SketchUp fill shape on multiple axes

Tags: 3d, sketchup

I'm trying to draw a roof with no success.

[image: Screenshot]

These areas should be filled that I can add roof texture there. I tried with sandbox and "from contour" but it's not what I want (can't use a tile texture on it).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a plane. Planes should be automatically created, but if they are not, its a good idea to draw a line from corner to corner to force a plane to be created. Once a valid solid plane has been created you should be able to use material fills.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this didn't help.

Comment: Were the planes not created?

Comment: See the picture above. The lines are "cross-axis". SketchUp won't create surfaces on those situations.

Comment: Probably because they're not perfectly flat planes. To check draw lines diagonally from corner to corner (making two triangles) and see if it turns into two triangular planes. If it does, then the problem is that the four lines you drew to form the quadrilateral aren't all on the same plane (hence a plane surface can not be made)